# How to derive velocity in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

In one of my aerodynamics classes i need to use the following derivation to convert the velocity components u and v to a polar coordinate system:

$$
v_r = u \cos(\theta) + v \sin(\theta) \\
v_t = v \cos(\theta) - u \sin(\theta)
$$

I'm trying to get to this derivation to understand it but I cant figure it out.
Can someone show me how they converted the velocity in Cartesian coordinate's to polar coordinates?
[image]

Comment: The position vector $\mathbf{r}$ is defined as $[~x~~y~]$ in the standard basis or in polar coordinates as $(~r\cos\theta~~r\sin\theta~)$. Take time derivatives of each component and use the chain rule.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258629/components-of-velocity-in-polar-co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

Let us introduce $[x, y]^T = [r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta]^T$. The velocity is given by time derivative of this position vector.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\cos\theta -r\sin \theta~\dot{\theta} \\
\dot{r}\sin\theta + r\cos\theta~\dot{\theta}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\implies \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\
\dot{y}\\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -r\sin \theta\\
\sin\theta &+ r\cos \theta \\
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{r}\\ \dot{\theta}\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, invert the matrix on the right hand side and you will arrive at the expression in your question.

$$
\implies \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
\dot{\theta}\\
\end{bmatrix} =\dfrac{1}{r}\begin{bmatrix}
r\cos\theta & r\sin \theta\\
-\sin\theta &+ \cos \theta \\
 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}\\ \dot{y}\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\implies \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
\dot{\theta}\\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)~\dot{x} + \sin(\theta)~\dot{y}\\
-\dfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)~\dot{x}+ \dfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)~\dot{y} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\implies \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{r}\\
r\dot{\theta}\\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta~\dot{x} + \sin\theta~\dot{y}\\
-\sin\theta~\dot{x}+ \cos\theta~\dot{y} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that $v_t=r\dot{\theta}$.